# How to displace/replace widget controls for overlapping widgets?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have two widgets on the same position (overlapping). The first one is a slider and the second one is a semi transparent search bar on the top of the slider. The only problem with this is that the widget controls are shown in the same spot (in admin mode) so it is very difficult to select and edit any of the widgets. In addition the apos-admin-bar is also on the very same spot and it makes things even more difficult. Is there any way to move/replace the admin-bar and/or the widgets control-bar?[overlapping controls image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Zzz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much about the widgets, you may be able to solve this with some of the widget config options. When declaring the singleton, you can pass a `controls` object, and tell it where to place the admin-ui. For example:

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'foo', 'bar', {
  controls: {
    position: 'top-right'
  }
}) }}
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/adding-editable-content-to-pages#take-control-of-your-controls